# Android ACRA with handled exceptions

Tags: android, exception, report, try-catch

I am using ACRA (Application Crash Report for Android) to send data when unhandled exceptions occur.

Methods like openFileOutput() requires me to try and catch iOExceptions. Since the exception is in a try catch block, ARCA is not triggered. However I would still like to receive and see the stacktrace. Are there any ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If handling the `IOException`, etc. doesn't really make sense (i.e., there is really nothing you can do about it), wrap it in a `RuntimeException` and throw it. ACRA will catch and report this. If you don't want to crash the app, catch and handle it, then use `handleException()` to send a report manually:

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(caughtException);
```

More details [here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-for-caught-exceptions-or-for-unexpected-application-state-without-any-exception)

Comment: Is there any option for prevent ACRA from sending duplicate exception? (Duplicate exception means a duplicate exception from specific device)

Comment: Deduplicate exceptions at the server. You can't reasonably do this at client side, without maintaining a database of *all* exceptions sent so far.