# How to set ACRA to handle special kind of exceptions

Tags: android, acra

I configured ACRA and it works fine. I just want to know if its possible to force ACRA to handle special kind of exceptions like IOException and do nothing for other kinds.

Answer (score 1):

ACRA means **Application Crash Report for Android** Its for indicating and showing the error to the developers.

Its not used to handling the errors.

Comment: I know but is there any way to do it?

Comment: @MojtabaMahamed Don't you know about the Exception handling mechanism in android ?

Comment: @GrlsHu Of course I know but the issue is I cant clarify it to you :)

Comment: @MojtabaMahamed Then i am sorry i can not give you any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can handle those exceptions. But you have to be smart.
Please take a look at this post: [Android ACRA with handled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945256/android-acra-with-handled-exceptions)

Comment: I mean I want ACRA to catch IOException without try catch block. I want to configure ACRA to handle only and only IOException or any special exception

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand the Java Exception mechanism.

An IOException is a checked Exception. That means your code needs to deal with it in order to compile. You can certainly use ACRA to notify you of that exception when you explicitly deal with it.